# JIRA 5.2 RPC SOAP service wrapped as RESTFul -- Insert data into custom database fields

Tags: rest, soap, jira, custom-fields

Jira 5.2 SOAP API is wrapped in a WCF RESTFul service by utilising methods from SOAP API as below fyi.

```
            public Message GetCustomFields()
            {
            try
            {
            token = this.
            Login(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("JiraUser"),
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("JiraPassword"));

            RemoteField[] remoteCompoment = jiraSoapService.getCustomFields(token);
            return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateJsonResponse<RemoteField[]>  
           (remoteCompoment);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

All the methods are working as expected.

Query:- Custom database tables are used to populate custom fields in Jira using Kepler.

Form builder Frevvo is used to call the Jira RESTFul service to create Jira issue. Would appreciate help in creating an isssue with custom fields.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jira SOAP api provides RemoteCustomFieldValue partial class to create an issue using Custom Fields.

```
        //custom fields
        remoteCustomFields = new List<RemoteCustomFieldValue>();
        XmlNodeList customFieldList = doc.SelectNodes("//customFieldValues");
        foreach (XmlNode customField in customFieldList)
        {

            XmlNodeList customFieldValueList = doc.SelectNodes("//customFieldValues/Values");
            remoteCustomFields.Add(
                new RemoteCustomFieldValue
                    {

                        customfieldId = customField.SelectSingleNode("customFieldId").InnerText,
                        values = customFieldValueList.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n=> n.InnerText).ToArray()

                    });
        }
```

useful resource: https://svn.atlassian.com/svn/public/contrib/jira/jira-rpc-samples/src/java/com/atlassian/jira_soapclient/SOAPClient.java